# AFNetworking asynchronous POST request for username and password parameter (Objective-C iOS)

Tags: php, ios, asynchronous, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am new to iOS Development and I am stuck in my small project where I have to create asynchronous POST request to the php website. I read resources online and found AFNetworking is best to do this work so I installed AFNetworking 2.4 using cocoapods through terminal. I have a view controller which has 2 textfields (Username and Password), Whenever I press Login button, I to send an asynchronous POST request to php website.The POST request must contain the parameters 'username' and 'password' and will receive a JSON response back with a 'code' and a 'message'. I have to display the parsed code and message in a UIAlert along with how long the api call took in miliseconds. The only valid login is username: Yomaki password:asdfgh. When a login is successful, tapping 'OK' on the UIAlert should bring us back to the MainMenuViewController. Please look at what I have tried code below. I have tried following couple tutorials online but didnt work.

Please look at the code below,

```
(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender

{

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"Yomaki": _usernameTextField, @"asdfgh": _passwordTextField};

    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"PHP URL HERE"]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

}
```

Please help me with the code since this is the first time I am sending asynchronous POST request to the php website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing is sending the request, also note that "POST" has not been specified. Checkout some of the tutorials that show how to use `AFNetworking`.

Comment: Zaph, thanks for the help and I did check out some tutorials and corrected what I needed in my code. also can you check my comment  that I made to Rob below, I really dont know whats goin on. can you help with it? thanks in advance and appreciated your help!

Comment: I made it work by adding below code.manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `_usernameTextField` (the `UITextField`), but rather `_usernameTextField.text` or, perhaps better, `self.usernameTextField.text` (the `NSString` property of that test field). The same is true with the password.

I'd also avail yourself of the `POST` method:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"userid": self.usernameTextField.text, @"password": self.passwordTextField.text};

[manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Note, in your dictionary, you're replaced the field names (presumably something like `userid` and `password`, though check with your web service authors) with what appear to be sample userid/password values. I think you want to restore the original field names.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Ok I did the correction as you suggested and added the code you stated. I am still not able to get the kind of response I want for some reason.When I press the Login button in simulator, it doesnt do anything at all, it also doesnt give me the NSLog message we wrote in block. also it would be great if you could tell me how can I create an alert that will show message when not able to log in and when we enter right password alert would show login successful message and would take us back to the root view controller.? Thanks for the help !!

Comment: If you're not seeing either of these `NSLog` statements, it makes me suspect that it's not reaching this bit of code at all. Make sure your `IBAction` is properly hooked up. Put a `NSLog` or breakpoint before the `POST` call, and that should help you confirm that it's not running at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it by using manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

Comment: Yep, if your server code neglected to add the header, that `acceptableContentTypes` will get around that. (That doesn't explain your earlier reported behavior, that neither the success nor failure blocks were called, but I gather you got around that.) Personally, I'd just fix the server code to send the right header, but whatever works...

Answer (score 0):

From: [Junda Ong](http://samwize.com/2014/05/10/tutorial-on-using-afnetworking-2-dot-0/) Tutorial

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"yourURL"
   parameters: parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject); }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
```

Comment: Hello Zaph, thanks for the help. I did post the code but it doesnt do anything when I click on login button in simulator. Can you help me determine whats wrong. It doesnt even write NSLog messages. Do you know how can I create an alert to show wrong password and if right, ok button on alertview would take us to rootviewcontroller.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basic debugging is in order. Does the code even get called?, use the debugger and breakpoints, `NSLog()` prior to the m message POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL * url = @"your url";
NSString * user = ([userField.text length] == 0) ? @"" : userField.text;
NSString * pass = ([passField.text length] == 0) ? @"" : passField.text;

NSMutableDictionary * postVars = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[postVars setObject:user forKey:@"username"];
[postVars setObject:pass forKey:@"password"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:url parameters:postVars success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){

        if ([responseObject objectForKey:@"code"]) && ([responseObject objectForKey:@"message"]){

            NSString * code = [responseObject objectForKey:@"code"];
            NSString * message = [responseObject objectForKey:@"message"];

        }

    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // something went wrong with your http post

}];
```